# Magento 2 installation: Avoid "SHOW DATABASES" privilege - Error 1227 Access denied

Tags: database, magento2, privileges

I was trying to install Magento 2 but I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; 
you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this 
operation, query was: SHOW DATABASES
```

Since I am useing a shared hosting (My host provider is Aruba) I've tried to give myself the SUPER PRIVILEGES but of course it didn't work.

Is there a way I can force Magento to "avoid" running the SHOW DATABASES query to solve the problem?